# Minimum Information to be kept on importing OSM data to use it for creating random start and ent points

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, import, osm2pgsql

I want to only import the minimum of data from OpenStreetMap, to be able to distribute random start and end points for a simulation in administrative areas in germany. I found this file https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/empty.style which will act as my starting point.

Basically what I need are the bundaries of the districts, what type of distict it is and the streets. Nice to have would be if it is an area, where people life, office buildings or factories, since people commute between their home and work.

What I came up with so far is this. My Question to you: Am I missing something? Did I put in too much?

Generally I want to have a small database with the correct datatypes etc.

```
# osm2pgsql style file for simulation of commuter routes.
# The data is mainly used to determine random start and destination points
# for the route generation

# OsmType   Tag                     Type    Flags
# Insert your own columns here, or change phstore to polygon below
node,way    access                          text    linear
node,way    admin_level                     int4    linear
node,way    amenity                         text    polygon
node,way    area                            text    # hard coded support for area=1/yes => polygon is in osm2pgsql
way         boundary                        text    polygon
node,way    building                        text    polygon
way         de:amtlicher_gemeindeschluessel int4    polygon
way         de:regionalschluessel           int4    polygon
node,way    highway                         text    linear
node,way    landuse                         text    polygon
node,way    name                            text    linear
node,way    name:de                         text    phstore
node,way    office                          text    phstore
node,way    place                           text    polygon
node,way    population                      text    linear  # sadly text is used here as well
node,way    route                           text    linear
node,way    type                            text    linear
node,way    z_order                         int4    linear  # This is calculated during import
way         way_area                        real            # This is calculated during import

# Deleted tags
node,way    note                    text    delete
node,way    note:*                  text    delete
node,way    source                  text    delete
node,way    source_ref              text    delete
node,way    source:*                text    delete
node,way    attribution             text    delete
node,way    comment                 text    delete
node,way    fixme                   text    delete
node,way    created_by              text    delete
node,way    odbl                    text    delete
node,way    odbl:note               text    delete
node,way    SK53_bulk:load          text    delete
node,way    tiger:*                 text    delete
node,way    NHD:*                   text    delete
node,way    nhd:*                   text    delete
node,way    gnis:*                  text    delete
node,way    geobase:*               text    delete
node,way    accuracy:meters         text    delete
node,way    sub_sea:type            text    delete
node,way    waterway:type           text    delete
node,way    KSJ2:*                  text    delete
node,way    yh:*                    text    delete
node,way    osak:*                  text    delete
node,way    kms:*                   text    delete
node,way    ngbe:*                  text    delete
node,way    naptan:*                text    delete
node,way    CLC:*                   text    delete
node,way    3dshapes:ggmodelk       text    delete
node,way    AND_nosr_r              text    delete
node,way    import                  text    delete
node,way    it:fvg:*                text    delete
```

EDIT: Updated the style file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving out `name` seems no good idea. Not every object in Germany has a `name:de` tag.

I would keep `landuse` to get the residential and industrial areas.

`access` would be nice to filter out private ways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I incorporated the suggested changes, since they make sense. Also fixed some bugs in the data types i.e. population since it also has "ca. 850" values